# How to change Visibility of Div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change visibility of DIV on pressing of button . whats wrong with this code

```
     <p id="myP">This is a p element.</p>

     <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Hide content of p</button>

     <script>
        function myFunction() {
           var which= document.getElementById("myP");

          if (which.style.visibility=="visible")
              which.style.visibility = "hidden"
          else
              which.style.visibility = "visible"
        }

     </script>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original HTML doesn't have `style="visibility: visible"`. So `which.style.visibility` returns `null`. Therefore, `if(which.style.visibility)` fails.

Add the explicit style and it should work.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var which = document.getElementById("myP");

  if (which.style.visibility == "visible")
    which.style.visibility = "hidden"
  else
    which.style.visibility = "visible"
}
```

```html
<p id="myP" style="visibility: visible;">This is a p element.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Hide content of p</button>
```

Comment: Thanks sir @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code should work. The only issue is that you aren't explicitly originally setting the `visibility` property (as your if-statement is checking for):

```
<!-- Since visibility wasn't there, your code couldn't detect it -->
<p id="myP" style='visibility: visible'>This is a p element.</p>
```

You could resolve this by adding it if it doesn't already exist :

```
function myFunction() {
  // Grab your element
  var which = document.getElementById('myP');
  // Hide it if it is explicitly visible or the visbility property is not set,
  // otherwise show it
  which.style.visibility = (which.style.visibility == 'visible' || !which.style.visibility) ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
I fixed the code, but it still faking on the first click when it intiliaze the display attribute. This solution is good only if you don't want to change the html tags.

Use style.display insead

```
function myFunction() {
       var which= document.getElementById("myP");

      if (which.style.display =="")
          which.style.display = "none"
      else
          which.style.display = ""
    }
```

Comment: nothing happens . if(none) display none ? ? @the scion

Comment: solved ! anyway thanks !

Answer (score 0):

JQuery toggle works great for this, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uddhf4rw/2/

```
<p id="myP">This is a p element.</p>

<button type="button">Hide content of p</button>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
      $("#myP").toggle();
    });
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The corrct property is

which.style.display

so

```
  function myFunction() {
   var which= document.getElementById("myP");

  if (which.style.display =="block" || which.style.display =="")
      which.style.display = "none"
  else
      which.style.display = "block"
}
```

this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/rixlabs/4Lghq2fL/) as example

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use onclick attribute. Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

The entire code

```
var paragraph = document.getElementById("myP"),
    currentState = window.getComputedStyle(paragraph, null).visibility;
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
   paragraph.style.visibility = paragraph.style.visibility === "hidden" || currentState === "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden";
});
```

Also consider using css display instead of visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Initially the value of which.style.visibility is unset try

```
    function myFunction() {
       var which= document.getElementById("myP");

      if (!which.style.visibility || which.style.visibility=="visible")
          which.style.visibility = "hidden"
      else
          which.style.visibility = "visible"
    }
```

or

```
<p id="myP" style="visibility: visible;">This is a p element.</p>
```